# QuickGraph find vertex with specific distance

Tags: c#, quickgraph

In QuickGraph - is there an algorithm to find all vertices that are in a specific distance from root vertex (or any other vertex)?

For example finding all vertices that their distance from root vertex is 2.

Comment: ShortestPathDijkstra?

Comment: In ShortestPathDijkstra we define source and target vertices, and then the algorithm find the shortest path between them. But here we need define the source vertex and the path distance(for example two) to an algorithm, and then get all states with this distance. By ShortestPathDijkstra algorithm we can check ALL vertices in the graph (as target) and then choose vertices with specific distance, not optimized!